# How to fake headrs to get data like human browsing

Tags: python, http-headers, instagram

I am using python to get instagram profile picture more than a year. Today when i checked functionality it stopped working. Problem is that instagram started to check if human browsing or bot. When human browsing then it will add original sized image to `sharedData`, when not then image is empty. To fix it i have tried to use fake headers. First added manually headers, then used UserAgent.

```
url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + request.args.get("username")
ua = UserAgent()
headers = {'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

But it doesn't helped. So my question is, how they check who is browsing?

Comment: instagram will still respond with _sharedData even you don't set user-agent. Is your target account private? Maybe you logged in when you use your browser, so you can see the private account you followed, but your crawler is not authenticated, so it won't get the data from private account.

Comment: @Colin yes Instagram still respond `_sharedData ` but there is not user data. When you go to user page using postman you will see just loading page.

Comment: By using postman, I can still get all user information from _sharedData without any user agent.

Comment: @Colin but for me it is just instagram icon. https://prnt.sc/t5vjej _shareData is not empty you are right. But user information like name, image, username... is empty.

Comment: No sure why you don't get the data. I can pull all those data properly. BTW, it's doc, text formate response, not JSON